# Subquery Slows Query down significantly

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to do a query that replaces multiple queries to produce a result set. I've got a fairly straight forward set of 1 to 1 joins, but one column I'm trying to get from a table that keeps multiple records per primary record. Basically it's like this:

meet_entries with a primary key id column and a bunch of other columns,
meet_entries_statuses, with an autoincrement id column and a foreign key to the id column of meet_entry

There may be multiple rows in meet_entry_statuses for each row in meet_entries. In my query, I'm trying to get the most recently added(so highest id number) row associated with the meet_entry primary key id.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
  meet_entries.id,
  member.firstname,
  member.surname,
  member.gender,
  member.dob,
  clubs.code,
  clubs.clubname,
  meet_entries.meals,
  meet_entries.massages,
  meet_entries.cost,
  meet_entries.cancelled,
  (SELECT meet_entry_status_codes.description
  FROM meet_entry_statuses, meet_entry_status_codes
  WHERE meet_entry_statuses.code = meet_entry_status_codes.id
  AND meet_entry_statuses.id = meet_entries.id
  ORDER BY meet_entry_statuses.id DESC
  LIMIT 1) as status,
  COUNT(DISTINCT meet_events_entries.id) as entries
FROM meet_entries, meet_events_entries, member, clubs, meet_entry_statuses, meet_entry_status_codes
WHERE meet_entries.meet_id = ?
  AND meet_entries.id = meet_events_entries.meet_entry_id
AND meet_entries.member_id = member.id
AND meet_entries.club_id = clubs.id
GROUP BY meet_entries.id
;
```

Adding the bit:

```
(SELECT meet_entry_status_codes.description
FROM meet_entry_statuses, meet_entry_status_codes
WHERE meet_entry_statuses.code = meet_entry_status_codes.id
AND meet_entry_statuses.id = meet_entries.id
ORDER BY meet_entry_statuses.id DESC
LIMIT 1) as status,
```

takes the query from being .2 of a second, to never finishing. There are only 10 matching rows in meet_entries. There are about 50 rows in the meet_entries_statuses appropriate to the 10 rows in meet_entries, but as I say I'm trying to only get 1 row for each meet_entries row. Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure why you would join with `meet_entry_statuses` and `meet_entry_status_codes` without any join conditions.  Doing so means that you are doing a cross join.  So if there are N rows in `meet_entries`, and M and P rows in the above two tables respectively, you end up generating N x M x P rows.

Can you try taking out the two joins. I marked them out in the following rewritten query:

```
SELECT
    meet_entries.id,
    member.firstname,
    member.surname,
    member.gender,
    member.dob,
    clubs.code,
    clubs.clubname,
    meet_entries.meals,
    meet_entries.massages,
    meet_entries.cost,
    meet_entries.cancelled,
    (SELECT 
            meet_entry_status_codes.description
        FROM 
            meet_entry_statuses         as mes
            , meet_entry_status_codes   as mesc
        WHERE 
            meet_entry_statuses.code = meet_entry_status_codes.id
            AND meet_entry_statuses.id = meet_entries.id
        ORDER BY meet_entry_statuses.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as status,
    COUNT(DISTINCT meet_events_entries.id) as entries
FROM 
    meet_entries                    as me 
    , meet_events_entries           as mee 
    , member                        as m 
    , clubs                         as c 
    , meet_entry_statuses           as mes      -- try taking this out
    , meet_entry_status_codes       as mesc     -- try taking this out
WHERE 
    meet_entries.meet_id = ?
    AND meet_entries.id = meet_events_entries.meet_entry_id
    AND meet_entries.member_id = member.id
    AND meet_entries.club_id = clubs.id
GROUP BY meet_entries.id
;
```

Comment: That's definitely made the difference. I hadn't realised that including them in the FROM clause without a JOIN did that.